# How to reverse string word by word in SQL SERVER

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to reverse string word by word suppose I have input

- I/P : 'My Name is sachin'
- O/P : 'sachin is Name My'

I have created this code but it keeps running:

```
declare @I varchar(20)
declare @O varchar(20)
declare @T varchar(20)
set @I='My Name is sachin'
set @O=''
while CHARINDEX(' ',@I)>0
begin
set @T=substring(REVERSE(@I),1,charindex(' ',REVERSE(@I))-1)
set @O=@O+' '+REVERSE(@T)
set @I=reverse(STUFF(REVERSE(@I),1,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@I))-1,''))
end
```

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: well if the string still contains spaces it will never terminate (somewhat stating the obvious)

Comment: Do you really need to do this in SQL Server?  This would be _much_ easier in a programming language like Java or C#.

Comment: if sql-server which version?

Comment: MitchWheat and TimBiegeleisen thank you for your replay i found solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altered your query a little, try this.

```
 declare @I varchar(20)
 declare @O varchar(20)
 declare @T varchar(20)
 set @I='My Name is sachin'
 set @O=''
 while CHARINDEX(' ',@I)>0
 begin
     set @T=left(reverse(@i),charindex(' ',reverse(@i))-1)
     set @O=@O+' '+REVERSE(@T)
     set @I=left(@i,len(@i)-(1+len(@t)))
     If CHARINDEX(' ',@I)=0
        set @O=@O+' '+@i
     select @o
 end
```

'If' block is added to append the last word, as the 'Empty Space' will not be available to append the last word in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

**Modified:**

---

```
SELECT LTRIM(
(SELECT N' ' + x.display_term
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"Your Name is Georgel"', 0, 0, 0) AS x
ORDER BY x.occurrence DESC
FOR XML PATH('')))
```

---

Comment: declare @I varchar(20)
 declare @O varchar(20)
 declare @T varchar(20)
 set @I='My Name is sachin'
 set @O=''
 while CHARINDEX(' ',@I)>0
 begin
     set @T=left(reverse(@i),charindex(' ',reverse(@i))-1)
     set @O=@O+' '+REVERSE(@T)
     set @I=left(@i,len(@i)-(1+len(@t)))
     If CHARINDEX(' ',@I)=0
        set @O=@O+' '+@i
     
 end
 select @o

Answer (score 0):

in SQL Server 
1) Function to split string copied from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/
 
2) stuff the split string to one in reverse

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[usr_funSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX), pos smallint identity(1,1)   -- added position field
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END


select result = stuff((select ' ' + splitdata from dbo.[usr_funSplitString]('My Name is sachin',' ') order by pos desc
FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Comment: Instead of 1 you can use String_Split function in SQL 2016 :)

Comment: Yup since im on 2012 could not use it

Answer (score 0):

Here you need customize split string UDF.Or you need split string UDF which return row number.

so i f you create UDF from don't use master..spt_values.use Number table

Try this,

```
declare @t table(col1  varchar(50))
insert into @t values ('My Name is sachin')
declare @Delimiter as varchar(10)=' '

;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT col1
        ,ca.number
    FROM @t t
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 1 number

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DISTINCT number + 1
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE number > 0
            AND (SUBSTRING(col1, number, 1) = @Delimiter)
            AND number <= len(col1)
        ) ca
    )
    ,cteLen (
    N1
    ,col1
    ,L1
    )
AS (
    SELECT s.number
        ,col1
        ,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, col1, s.number), 0) - s.number, 4000)
    FROM cte s
    )
    ,CTE1
AS (
    SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY l.N1
            )
        ,n1
        ,l1
        ,Item = SUBSTRING(col1, l.N1, l.L1)
    FROM cteLen l
    )
SELECT TOP 1 (
        SELECT @Delimiter + item
        FROM cte1
        ORDER BY itemnumber DESC
        FOR XML path('')
        )
FROM cte1
```

Answer (score 0):

One *simple* solution (but far from being perfect) is to use `sys.dm_fts_parser` function (reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-parser-transact-sql)) thus:

```
SELECT LTRIM(
(SELECT N' ' + x.display_term
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser('"Your Name is Georgel", 0, 0, 0) AS x
ORDER BY x.occurence DESC
FOR XML PATH('')))
```